# Not able to use JavaScript File in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a number of JavaScript Functions which call on asp.net controls to get values from by use of  `document.getElementById('<%= txtBox1.ClientID%>').value`.

When I migrated my code to a JavaScript file separate from the markup, and then run the page the functions are failing when it reaches this type of code  `document.getElementById('<%= txtBox1.ClientID%>').value`.

Is it not possible to have javascript in a separate file when using `document.getElementById`?

Comment: why don't you use FunctionName(textboxValue){logic here;} and pass parameter on the js file

Comment: Javascript is not processed by the ASP engine that does those substitutions.

Comment: Because it is ASP.Net and it will not find the control.

Comment: You could give your control a unique class name, then reference it by that class name instead of the ID. I usually use the MVVM pattern so I avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the mark @Andy5 - can I ask what method you used to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript files are static, meaning they are not processed by IIS, and will therefore reach the browser in the same state as you left them (i.e. they will not have inline blocks changed).

The simplest is to set the `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the `<asp:TextBox>`.  This will stop ASP.NET doing it's normal thing of creating `<input type="text" id="ctl01_txtBox1">` and instead will create simply `<input type="text" id="txtBox1">`.

**However** this will only work if you only have single `txtBox1` (with `ClientIDMode="Static"`) in your entire page, including any usercontrols.

---

Another way to get around this would be to create a variable for the container that the controls live in and use that as the base, for example in your page or usercontrol...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var m_base = "<%=Me.ClientID%>_";
</script>
```

Then in your static javascript file, have...

```
document.getElementById(m_base + "txtBox1").value
```

But this obviously is only really useful if you're using MasterPages and usercontrols... and could be quite difficult to setup correctly (and debug)

Comment: how is static useful when we are using masterpages and usercontrols??

Comment: Erm, if you have to ask that @brykneval, then I'm not sure you understand the question. The "ClientIDMode=`Static`" was created **for** masterpage and usercontrols

Comment: Or are you @brykneval mistaking my last paragraph to be part of the `ClientIDMode="Static"` bit of the answer.  In which case it isn't... it's part of the "Another way to get around this" bit

Comment: I guess ClientIDMode=Static is best when using standalone rather than using with usercontrols and masterpage coz when using with multiple masterpage and usercontrols it creates a unique name for the elements created on html

Comment: Sorry @brykneval but I think we must be at cross-purposes, because you're making no sense to me at all.  The whole point of the `Static` was for exactly this type of thing, when using master pages and usercontrols